# what is irq/308-mxt224_ in Android system?

Tags: android, process

What is this the irq/308-mxt224_ process? 
More specifically, what is the function of this process.
I found this process is very active in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the threaded interrupt handler for the touchscreen controller.

Answer (score 2):

Going by the letters of the description yielded a Atmel mXT 224 touchscreen so I guess there's nothing to worry about :)

More than likely its just erroneous spamming of the information in the logcat by the process/kernel driver level.